# Automatically close the parent cell in a grouped set

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, document-creation

There are several questions in Mma.SE related to programmatically opening and closing cells, but I could not find quite what I'm seeking.

Here's a minimal example:

```
CellPrint[
   {ExpressionCell[x + y,
       Background -> LightOrange, 
       "Equation", 
       CellGroupingRules -> "OutputGrouping"]}]
```

When I evaluate this code it produces (almost) what I want:  the expression in the `Equation` cell, properly grouped with the code that produced it.

However I would like to automatically *collapse* (`Close`) the source code cell, while preserving the existing grouping.  I would like to go back, if necessary, to manually open the source cell, but the default should be that upon execution the source cell closes.

My kludge at present is to manually double click on the output cell, thereby collapsing the source code cell, but I'd rather it be automatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Cell[CellPrint[{ExpressionCell[x + y, Background -> LightOrange, 
     "Equation", CellGroupingRules -> "OutputGrouping"]}], 
  CellEpilog -> SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellOpen -> False]];
```

Comment: Yep.  Perfect.  Thanks!  ($+1$, $\checkmark$)

Comment: The outermost `Cell` is redundant, because what really works is `SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellOpen -> False]`, which can simply be placed on the next line after `CellPrint`.

Comment: Good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CellEpilog :> (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, GeneratedCell];
   FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"])]
```

Simply evaluate that in your Notebook, and then after evaluation every input cell will be automatically hidden in a closed `CellGroup` containing its output(s), which will become the only what is visible:

[image: screenshot]

Inspired by these answers:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29393/280
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/683/280

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I didn't get the errors you mentioned (v. 11.3), and I don't want this automatic closure to occur for *every* cell, so setting a default might not be appropriate.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In the second linked answer you can find another approach, which may be more appropriate for you.

Comment: Yep.  Thanks very much.  (I'm only now learning notebook-level programming.).  I'd *REALLY* like to solve the following problem, which has remained unanswered for years.  Perhaps you can help!  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72903/header-and-footer-banners-in-slide-show-style